# Printing position (starting from 1) and the element item, for each element in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Given the array below, I want to print the position (starting with 1) and the element item, for each element in the array in a single line.

```js
let bag = ""

let arr = [1, 2, 3, "Ram", 2, "Chris"];

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]) {
    bag = bag + arr[i] + " ";
  }
}
console.log(bag);
```

I want the log given to be similar to this, having position starting from 1 and the item of that element, for each element in a single line.

`1: 1. 2: 2. 3: 3. 4: Ram. 5: 2. 6: Chris`

Comment: Your code does not do anything to include the position. Also, arrays in JavaScript start at 0, not 1.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to add a `}`  to have a working code

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 2):

The following solution makes use of the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods on arrays:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, "Ram", 2, "Chris"];
console.log(arr.map(function(element, position) {
  return `${position + 1}: ${element}`;
}).join(". "));
```

Comment: The `.` is not added after the numbers only, it's added after all but the last one..

Comment: I have corrected (actually, simplified) my answer accordingly.

Comment: Greater than mine 

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
let str = '';

const arr = [1, 2, 3, "Ram", 2, "Chris"];

for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  str += (arr[i] && (i < arr.length - 1)) ? i + ': ' + arr[i] + ', ' : i + ': ' + arr[i]
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with two ways, the regular way with loops, and the advanced way with methods:

---

**With Loops:**

```js
let bag = ""
let arr = [1, 2, 3, "Ram", 2, "Chris"]
for (let pos in arr) {
    bag += pos + ": " + arr[pos]
    if( pos != arr.length-1 ) bag += ". "
}
console.log(bag)
```

---

**With Methods:**

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, "Ram", 2, "Chris"]

let result = arr.map((item, pos) => {
  return `${pos}: ${item}${pos != arr.length-1 ? "." : ""}`
}).join(" ")

console.log( result )
```